# How to configure channel url for a Deezer inapp application?

Tags: deezer

When testing my deezer inapp application, I get the following message:

> You must configure you app url: developers.deezer.com/myapps/app/xxxxx/edit You must configure your app channel url

There is no parameter 'Channel url' that can be setup in the application manager for my app.

After checking the inapp demo (http://developers.deezer.com/inapp/config/permissions), it seems I should have an inapp section, but it does not exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The channel URL to configure for the inapps is only available for applications which are considered and validated as partners, that's why you can not see it in the interface.

Comment: Thanks. So how can I test my application? Should I make a case to Deezer to be considered as a valid partner?